# How to know if my element was taken out of grid layout group?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working in a unity project. In here I have a game object with a grid layout group. I also have elements that I need to put in this layout group.
For this I implemented the drag and drop function:
For example

```
public class DragDropMove : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IDragHandler
{
    //[SerializeField] private Canvas canvas;
    private RectTransform rect;
    private CanvasGroup canvasgroup;
    private void Awake()
    {
        rect = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        canvasgroup = GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    }
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("On begin drag");
        canvasgroup.alpha = .6f;
        canvasgroup.blocksRaycasts = false;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("On drag");
        rect.anchoredPosition += eventData.delta;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("On end drag");
        canvasgroup.alpha = 1f;
        canvasgroup.blocksRaycasts = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("On pointer down");
    }
}
```

In the drop function I have a list to put the elements I drop in the grid. I also need this to know the order of elements in grid.

```
public class ItemSlot : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler 
{
    public string cell = "Vacio";
    public GameObject celText;
    public List<string> droppedItemsList;
    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData) {
        Debug.Log("esto " + eventData.pointerDrag);
        Debug.Log("OnDrop");
        cell = this.transform.name;
        celText.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Elemento en casillero: " + cell;
        string droppedObject = eventData.pointerDrag.name;
        Debug.Log("Dropped " + droppedObject);
        droppedItemsList.Add(droppedObject);
        foreach (string str in droppedItemsList)
        {
            Debug.Log("Items in list " + str);
        }
        /*
        if (eventData.pointerDrag != null) {
            eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
        }*/
    }
}
```

With this implementation I know when an item is dropped but is there a way of knowing when an item was taken out? I need this so I can remove the item from the list. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help

Comment: On enddrop check where it was dropped to and remove it from the list if it was dropped somewhere else?

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I will try doing that